# Many-to-many relationship causing only one object to be added instead of multiple

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities, Orders and Products, the relationship between the two is many to many, I have set the relationship but when I try to add several products to an order, I get only the first product added not the the whole list of objects. It happens even when i manually add them to the databse, the output is the same as posting them from postman or talend api tester.You will find screenshots at the end to understand more about what my issue is.

Here is my Orders entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Orders")
public class Orders implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name="idorder")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "orders_sequence")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "orders_sequence")
private Long idOrder;


@Column(name="idclient")
private Long idClient;

@Column(name="idmanager")
private String idManager;


@Column(name="iddeliveryman")
private String idDeliveryMan;


@Column(name="dateorders")
@JsonFormat(pattern="mm-dd-yyyy")
private Date dateOrder;


@Column(name="totalprice")
private double totalPrice;

@Column(name="status")
private String orderStatus;

@ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL } , fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(
    name = "orders_products", 
    joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "idorder") }, 
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "idproduct") }
)
private Set<Products> products_orders = new HashSet<>() ;




@PrePersist
public void onCreate() {
    this.dateOrder = new Date();
}
    
//getters and setters

}
```

My Products entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Products")
@JsonIdentityInfo(
    generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
    property = "idProduct")
public class Products implements Serializable{

@Id
@Column(name="idproduct")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "products_sequence")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "products_sequence")
private Long idProduct;

@Column(name="labelproduct")
private String label;

@Column(name="priceproduct")
private int priceProduct;

@Column(name="descriptionproduct")
private String descriptionProduct;



@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "products" )
private List<Menu> menus;


@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "products_orders" )
private Set<Orders> orders=new HashSet<>();

//getters and setters
}
```

My Orders Contoller:

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin
public class OrdersController {

@Autowired
private OrdersRepository ordersRepository;
    
@Autowired
private ClientsRepository clientsRepository;

@Autowired 
private ProductsRepository productsRepos;
    

@PostMapping(path="orders/client/create/{idClient}")
public ResponseEntity<?> createOrderClient(@Valid @RequestBody Orders order, @PathVariable Long 
    idClient){
    
    Set<Products> products=new HashSet<>();
    
    double price =0; 
    
    
    Clients client=clientsRepository.findByPhone(idClient);
    order.setIdClient(client.getPhone());
    
    for (Products p: order.getProducts_orders()) {
        
        Products product = productsRepos.findByIdProduct(p.getIdProduct());
        price = price + product.getPriceProduct();          
        products.add(product);          
        System.out.println(product.getLabel() + product.getPriceProduct()+ product.getIdProduct());
        
    
    }
    
    order.setTotalPrice(price);
    order.setOrderStatus("Pending");
    order.setDateOrder(new Date());     
    order.setProducts_orders(products);
    Orders newOrder = ordersRepository.save(order);
    
    return new ResponseEntity<Orders>(newOrder,HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

Here are some screenshots :

[My Logs when getting the orders list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiIFU.png)
[Input of submitting an order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/af7tJ.png)

[Output of submitting an order with two products](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WfiN.png)

Comment: The two rows were created in the `orders_products` table? Or just one row?

Comment: @francisconeto the two rows were added

Comment: so I think the problem here is not "Many-to-many relationship causing only `one object to be added instead of multiple`". The problem seems to happen during object `retrieval`. Do you have a service to retrieve the order? can you tell me if this service is just returning one product? And can you print the sqls executed by hibernate during the order retrieval?

Comment: @francisconeto my method of retirieving is a simple get @GetMapping("orders/orderslist/{idOrder}")
 public Orders getSpecificOrder(@PathVariable Long idOrder) {
  return ordersRepository.findByIdOrder(idOrder);
 }

Comment: @francisconeto i just added a screenshot of my logs and its retrieving one product as an object and the id of the second product as plain test same as shown in the output

Comment: @francisconeto i just added a list of 3 objects and the output was that only two objects were shown and the third one was plain text, so its showing -1 of total products and i dont know why that is happening !

Comment: Feels like the product 6255 is currently inserted in table `products_orders` (in a line of order 5) but it is not in table `Products` anymore... is that right? Do you see product 6255 in table `Products` or it is only in the many-to-many table `products_orders`?

Comment: The only strange thing I see in your code is the `CascadeType.ALL` in the `@ManyToMany`. You may try to remove the cascade ALL from this `ManyToMany`... It is not recommended cascade all in manyToMany and using it like this may have a side effect of deleting lines of Product or Orders table as explained here: https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-use-the-manytomany-annotation-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: @francisconeto it is in both tables, products_orders and products. i removed the all few minutes ago just before seeing your comment, i saw that its a bad practice so i changed it but still having the same issue, and strange thing is its taking -1 from the total of products added its really strange